# R custom running function

Tags: r, dplyr, lapply, rolling-computation

How can I achieve same results without loop?
It's equivalent of scan function in reactiveX but with custom logic (http://reactivex.io/rxjs/img/scan.png)

```
for (i in 2:nrow(x)) {
  x$running_number[i] <-
    ifelse(abs(x$running_number[(i - 1)] - x$numbers[i])  > max_diff,
           x$numbers[i],
           x$running_number[(i - 1)])
}
```

EDIT:

Not sure I asked correctly after your reply. Take a look at this dataframe

```
x <- data.frame(
  c(1000, 1010, 1020, 1030, 1100, 1120, 1140, 1150, 1200),
  c(1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1100, 1200)
)

colnames(x) <- c('input_v', 'output_v')
```

Given x$input_v need to get x$output_v

I can express condition like :

```
x$output_v <-
  ifelse(
    abs(x$input_v - somehow_get_me_last_assigned_x_output_v) > 90,
    x$input_v,
    somehow_get_me_last_assigned_x_output_v
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `diff` to find the difference between the adjacent elements, create the logical condition with 'max-diff', use that in `ifelse` to return either the 'numbers' or the `lag` of 'running_number'

```
with(x, ifelse(c(FALSE, abs(diff(running_number)) > max_diff), 
      numbers, c(NA, running_number[-nrow(x)])))
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
  mutate(running_number = case_when(c(FALSE, abs(diff(running_number)) > 
             max_diff)0 ~ numbers, TRUE ~ lag(running-number)))
```

Comment: @AndrewVorobyov. i think the logic with `max_diff` which is 70 may not work in the example you updated.  YOu can try `with(x, ave(input_v, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(input_v) > 20)), FUN = function(x) x[1]))
[1] 1000 1000 1000 1000 1100 1100 1100 1100 1200`